# The literal stack isn't empty for entry (ui.absabs.harvard citation)

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm trying to write a research paper using BibTex and I'm having an issue with filling in the bibliography.  I've seen other questions related to this but they don't seem to help.  An example for what causes the error is

```
@ARTICLE{Binita_02,
       author = {{Abeysekara}, A.~U. and et al},
        title = "{HAWC observations of the acceleration of very-high-energy cosmic rays in the Cygnus Cocoon}",
      journal = {Nature Astronomy},
     keywords = {Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena},
         year = 2021,
        month = mar,
       volume = {5},
        pages = {465-471},
          doi = {10.1038/s41550-021-01318-y},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {2103.06820},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021NatAs...5..465A},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

I took it straight from  "https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021NatAs...5..465A/exportcitation" (they give citations in BibTex format).  I get the "the literal stack isn't empty for entry Binita_02" error both when I include the reduced and full author list, so that's not the issue.  Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?  I currently have 23 out of 55 sources giving these errors (they don't affect anything on the PDF side) and I would like to know what's missing for them.

Comment: Note, that you should always double check the data you get from online sources, sometimes they don't format it correctly. You should list a small document that causes the problem you're describing. This will also show us the bibtex style you're using, something you haven't listed

Comment: Note that the author is generally wrong here, it ought to list all the authors and thus thus one might confuse the bibtex style.

Comment: Yeah, `author = {{Abeysekara}, A.~U. and et al},` is fishy. It is best to list all authors, but if you absolutely cannot do that, you should use the keywords `and others`, i.e. `author = {Abeysekara, A. U. and others},` which are recognised by all good BibTeX styles.

Comment: Other than that the entry looks OK-ish. I could not reproduce an error with `natbib`'s standard `plainnat` style. You need to tell us which style gave you the error. This is best done in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: To publish in the Journal of Physical Chemistry?